# Is it possible to share Objects between applications without serialization?

Tags: c#, serialization, object, remoting, marshalling

Is it possible to share Objects between C# applications without serialization?

I need three apps to share an instance of the same object, but the object itself doesn't support serialization.

The scope is: I'm developing some apps to create some kind of interoperability between SVN and TFS repositories. But I don't want to connect to tfs server on the three apps (useless time consuming) since one of them is just a set of small utilities, and I don't want it to have a slow loading.

So I was thinking of using RemotingServices.Marshal, registering the connection object temporarily in a tcp channel, and calling the object whenever I need it in the other apps.

But here's the thing. Many objects in TeamFoundation.Client aren't serializable, so I get an error when trying to retrieve the object.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *direct* alternative to serialization is remoting, but that *also* requires changes to the types, so isn't going to work.

Rather than trying to serialize the TFS objects, I would write a object model that *resembles* the TFS objects (or better: the requests etc that you want to perform), and send *that*. Then reconstruct as needed. Essentially a shallow DTO layer on top of the *actual* objects.

Obviously you'll need to reconstruct the TFS model as needed (based on the DTO state), but that is life.

Comment: I see, that'll be a little troublesome I guess... Just curious, is there any way to "access" the object located in another process by getting its memory address or something?

Comment: Marshaling is your answer dude, but to be specific Marshaling by reference

Comment: But don't I need to use serializable objects to be able to use marshalling?

Comment: @Conrad - if they are `MarshalByRefObject`, then no - as the object never leaves; but then it needs to be `MarshalByRefObject` which is *more* of an overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. So I'm sort of back to square one: I can't share through serialization because my objects aren't serializable. And I can't share through marshalling by reference because my objects aren't MarshalByRefObject. Any other option seems complicated enough... I'm starting to think I should do everything in one app (single everything will work locally) and forget about splitting things up. Unless there's some sort of "trick" to do that

Comment: @Conrad - as long as the data you want to share is simple, a DTO-based API should be pretty trivial to implement.

Comment: I'm a bit clueless, never done that before...And most method calls seem to request something from the TFS connection. So even if I marshal the DTO wouldn't it crash because there is no connection? Unless, of course, if I prefetched everything that should be needed at the time it connects (and put it in the object to be remoted), and refresh every once in a while.

Comment: @Conrad - yes, to go that route you need to *forget* about the TFS objects - they are just how you populate the DTO model before transmitting it. Maybe a single app is easier ;p